# Android: YouTubePlayer does not work in childactivity

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, childactivity

I'm trying to implement a Video into my app. I thought I can use the YouTubePlayer API and open my Video. This is working fine if I open a normal new intent.

But it does not really work if I open the YouTubeVideoPlayer in my childActivity which has a menu on the bottom of the app.

This is how I try to open the Intent:

```
Intent video = new Intent(getParent(), MyYouTubeVideoPlayer.class);
TabGroupActivity videoActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
videoActivity.startChildActivity("Video", video);
```

> Its's working but then the Player sais: "An error occured while
>   initializing the YouTube player.

Has anyone an idea how I can implement the YouTubePlayer into my app within this ChildActivity?
Or is there an other better way to play my YouTube Video in my app?

Here are the YouTubePlayer Classes:

```
public class MyYouTubeVideoPlayer extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
  }

  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  }

}
```

Second Class:

```
public abstract class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity extends
        YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,

    YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {

        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {

            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();

        } else {

            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());

            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {

            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action

            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY,
                    this);

        }

    }

    protected abstract YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As I know, the youtube player just stop itself if you ad any view on the "YouTubePlayerView".**

**Because it will be just same as the Ads.**

By the way, I've made sample activity which uses most recent youtube api.

This source handle "**Orientation Problem**", "**Media Volume Problem**", "**Youtube Url Parsing Problem**"

1. This is the sample activity code

   https://gist.github.com/TheFinestArtist/5545437
2. Here is git project for sample app

   https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/SimpleYouTubePlayer
3. I also made sample app you can download

   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thefinestartist.simpleyoutubeplayer